# Codeiginiter multiple insert unexpectedly

Tags: codeigniter-3

My problem is when `$tipeKampanye` is **p3**, it's work well, but when `$tipeKampanye` is **visitor** `$this->Click_model->insertClickDetail` insert multiple row in my table and i don't know from where **images** value from like below:

[image]

here my controller code (and it is not in loop) :

```
if($this->session->userdata('ipUser')!==$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])
    {

        echo '1';
        $this->session->set_userdata('ipUser',$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
        $this->session->set_userdata('idClick',$this->Click_model->insertClick());
        $data=array(
            'id_click'=>$this->session->userdata('idClick'),
            'id_kampanye'=>$idKampanye,
            'code'=>$tipeKampanye

        );

        $this->Click_model->insertClickDetail( $data);

    }else{
        echo '2' ;
        $data=array(
            'id_click'=>$this->session->userdata('idClick'),
            'id_kampanye'=>$idKampanye,
            'code'=>$tipeKampanye

        );
        $this->Click_model->insertClickDetail($data);
    }
```

and this my **Click_model.php**

```
public function insertClick(){
    $this->db->insert('click','id');

    return $this->db->insert_id();
}

public function insertClickDetail($data=array()){


    return $this->db->insert('click_detail',$data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just adding  some code to remove unwanted value from array

```
public function insertClickDetail($data=array()){

    if(in_array('images',$data,true))
    {
        $data =  array_splice($array, 0, 0);
    }
    return $this->db->insert('click_detail',$data);
}
```